# hide android softkeyboard when one key on softkeyboard press

Tags: android, keyboard

I would like to hide my softkeyboard when one key on softkeyboard press.
After review, I found only ways to hide softkeybord after some event(eg. when use is on edit text)

Comment: you can use: (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN)

Answer (score 1):

hi here is the detail

**To show soft keyboard**

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
 mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

**To Hide soft keyboard**

```
  InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**and overriding onKeydownEvent hide the soft keyboard**

```
@Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  //hide the soft keyboard
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public class KeyBoard {

    public static void toggle(Activity activity){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm.isActive()){
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0); // hide
        } else {
            imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY); // show
        }
    }//end method
}//end class

KeyBoard.toggle(activity);
```